# Find that solution satisfying $ϕ$ satisfying $ϕ(0) = 0$, $ϕ'(0) = 1$, $ϕ''(0)=0$ for $y'''-4y'=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification, roots

**Problem:**

> Consider the equation
>              $y'''- 4y' = 0$
>
> Find that solution satisfying $ϕ(0) = 0$, $ϕ'(0) = 1$, $ϕ''(0)=0$.

**My solution:**

> The characteristic polynomial of $y'''- 4y' = 0$ is $r^3 - 4r = 0$.
>
> Then, $r(r^2 - 4) = 0$ **→** $r(r-2)(r+2) = 0$ **→** $r = 0,r = 2,r = -2$.
>
> Therefore, $ϕ(x) = c_1 + c_2e^{2x} + c_3e^{-2x}$
>
> As given,
>
> i. $ϕ(0) = c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = 0$
>
> ii. $ϕ'(x) = 2c_2e^{2x} - 2c_3e^{-2x}$ then, $ϕ'(0) = 2c_2 - 2c_3 = 1$
>
> iii. $ϕ''(x) = 4c_2e^{2x} + 4c_3e^{-2x}$ then, $ϕ''(0) = 4c_2 + 4c_3 = 0$. Therefore, $c_2 = -c_3$. Substituting $c_2$ in to ii yeilds $c_3 = \frac{-1}{4}$. Then $c_2 = \frac{1}{4}$. Substituting $c_2, c_3$ to i yields $c_1 = 0$.
>
> So, the solution satisfying $ϕ(0) = 0$, $ϕ'(0) = 1$, $ϕ''(0)=0$ is $ϕ(x) = \frac{1}{4}e^{2x} + \frac{-1}{4}e^{-2x}$

**But book says $ϕ(x) = \frac{sinh(2x)}{2}$. Can someone please verify my answer? Thanks!**

Comment: Your solution is $\phi(x) = \frac 12 \sinh(2x)$ and looks good to me. A $x$ in the denominator (as in the book solution) cannot be right and might be a typo.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, the denominator is just 2, not 2x

Comment: Then there is no difference between your solution and the one from the book :)

Comment: @MartinR Then how does $ϕ(x) = \frac{1}{4}e^{2x} + \frac{-1}{4}e^{-2x}$

equals $ϕ(x) = \frac{sinh(2x)}{2}$?

Comment: Lookup the definition of $\sinh $, e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_analytic_expressions.

Comment: You are correct it's just the exponential form of $sinh(\lambda x)$ is equal to $\dfrac{e^{\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda x}}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Note that by definition:
$$\sinh(x)\equiv \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
Thus:
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2x}=\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{4}=\frac{\sinh(2x)}{2}$$